# Obtener name+id de un servicio con Angular

Tags: json

Saludos estimados estoy trabajando con angular obteniendo el resultado de un servicio, el cual me falta obtener el nombre de géneros, pero el parámetro que me envía el servicio para el item genero es: genre_ids, lo cual me imprime los números de id correspondientes, necesito obtener los nombres de géneros por id.

este es el servicio y el html donde obtengo los resultados,

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class PeliculasService {

  results:any[] = [];
  cargando:boolean = false;

  constructor( private http:Http) {
    this.carga_info();
  }

  public carga_info() {
    this.http.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=041a697538db4c29730095424a6df704&primary_release_date.gte=2018-06-28&primary_release_date.lte=2018-07-19")
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data.json());
        this.cargando = true;
        this.results = data.json().results;
      })
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="listado">
    <li *ngFor="let item of _ps.results">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{item.poster_path}}">
        <div class="info-1">
          <div class="titulo">{{ item.title }}</div>
          <div class="genero">{{ item.genre_ids }}</div>
        </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

una duda que tengo, es que el servicio me arroja genre_ids, pero no nombres o un campo name, para obtenerlos, no se si se necesita hacer otra petición para obtener esos nombre y luego incluirlos en ese parámetro, de todas formas intente hacerlo así desde esta otra petición, pero sin éxito, igual dejo el otro servicio si es que fuera necesario.

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=041a697538db4c29730095424a6df704&language=en-US